# "hidden" RegEx?

Tags: c#, .net, regex

Is there any way in C# to use a Regex, but only return (with a Regex.Match) a part of the Regex? For example,

```
string input = "Hello my friend!";
string pattern = "\\w+ my friend.";
Console.WriteLine(Regex.Match(input, pattern)); //Returns "Hello my friend!"
```

But what if I just wanted the "Hello", or maybe just the punctuation at the end? I know I could do something like "`^\\w+`" (or even just `.split(' ')[0]`), but then that would match the first word of *any* input, and I'd only like it to match the first word if the rest of it matches with " `my friend.`" Is there any way to do this, or would it be simpler just to do

```
string input = "Hello my friend!";
string pattern = "\\w+ my friend.";
if (Regex.IsMatch(input, pattern))
{
    Console.WriteLine(input.Split(' ')[0]);
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("");
}
```

(sorry if this is really simple or if I'm missing something, I've just started really using Regexs)

Thanks,

Matthew

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apart form the capturing groups suggested in other answers, you can also use a lookahead. So you can use an expression like `"\\w+(?= my friend)"` and the entire match will only return the `\\w+` part.

In general, a pattern in the form `a(?=b)` where `a` and `b` are regular expressions matches `a` only if it is followed by `b` but does not match `b`.

Comment: thanks, this is exactly the type of "hidden" regex I was looking for :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use "groups" to capture a specific part of a string.  For example, let's say that you wanted to capture the name in `Hello, John!`.  Our Regex would look similar to this:

```
/Hello, (.+)/
```

The `()` (group) operator captures anything within it.  We could then use the following code to get the name.

```
var regex = new Regex(@"Hello, (.+)");
var match = regex.Match("Hello, John");

System.Console.WriteLine("Your name is {0}.", match.Groups[1]); // Your name is John.
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for *capturing groups* within Regex. You can identify a capturing group using parenthesis. For your particular example:

```
string input = "Hello my friend!";
string pattern = "(\\w+) my friend";
var match = Regex.Match(input, pattern);
Console.WriteLine(match.Groups[1]); // Prints "Hello"
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you could do it with a lookahead (untested, because I don't have any way to test c#)

```
"\\w+(?=\\s+my friend)"
```